# How to make a picture draggable again in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I read that it was not possible to reload a single div (or class) using javascript.

Then I found a way to change the picture inside a div from within a script.

```
<div class="bottom3" id="bottom3" align="center">
<img id="Image" src="blank.png">
</div>
```

In the script :

```
document.getElementById("Image").src = 'good.png';
```

And it can be undone with :

```
document.getElementById("Image").src = 'blank.png';
```

So I thought the solution could be to change the contents of the div from within the script. Then I could reload the div by writing a function called reset(); but for this div it failed :

```
<div class="middle3" id="middle3" align="center">
  <img id="equal" src="equal.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="68" height="69">
</div>
```

I tried :

```
  document.getElementById("equal").src = 'equal.png';
  document.getElementById("equal").ondragstart = function () { return true; };
  document.getElementById("equal").draggable = true;
  document.getElementById("equal").ondragstart = "drag(event)";
```

No way. It's as if the browser remembered that the picture had been moved and refused to put it back in it's original place no matter what.

I assume that "equal' is an element of "middle3", a child or something. But even if I try to write like that it doesn't function :

```
  document.getElementById("middle3").img.draggable = true;
  document.getElementById("middle3").img.ondragstart = "drag(event)";
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

November 4, 2020

Original state :

```
<div id="container">

<div class="up1" id = "up1" align="center">
  <p> </p>
</div>

<div class="up2" id = "up2" align="center" font="arial" size=18>
<p align="center" font="arial" size=18>
</p>
</div>

<div class="up3" id="up3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" align="center">
</div>

<div class="up4" id="up4" align="center">
<p> </p>
</div>

<div class="up5" id="up5" align="center">
<p> </p>
</div>

<div class="middle1" id="middle1" align="center">
<p> </p>
</div>

<div class="middle2" id="middle2" align="center">
  <img id="smaller" src="smaller.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="68" height="69">
</div>

<div class="middle3" id="middle3" align="center">
  <img id="equal" src="equal.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="68" height="69">
</div>

<div class="middle4" id="middle4" align="center">
  <img id="bigger" src="bigger.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="68" height="69">
</div>

<div class="middle5" id="middle5" align="center">
<p> </p>
</div>

</div> <!--Closes container-->
```

My function written with your help :

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#button").click(function(){

    $("#middle2").html('<img id="smaller" src="smaller.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="68" height="69">');
    $("#middle3").html('<img id="equal" src="equal.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="68" height="69">');
    $("#middle4").html('<img id="bigger" src="bigger.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="68" height="69">');
    
    $("#middle2").draggable();
    $("#middle3").draggable();
    $("#middle4").draggable();
    $('#middle2').draggable({disabled: false});
    $('#middle3').draggable({disabled: false});
    $('#middle4').draggable({disabled: false});
    document.getElementById("#middle2").ondragstart = drag;
    document.getElementById("#middle3").ondragstart = drag;
    document.getElementById("#middle4").ondragstart = drag;
    document.getElementById("#middle2").setAttribute("ondragstart", "drag(event)");
    document.getElementById("#middle3").setAttribute("ondragstart", "drag(event)");
    document.getElementById("#middle4").setAttribute("ondragstart", "drag(event)");
    
    $("#smaller").draggable();
    $("#equal").draggable();
    $("#bigger").draggable();
    $('#smaller').draggable({disabled: false});
    $('#equal').draggable({disabled: false});
    $('#bigger').draggable({disabled: false});
    document.getElementById("#smaller").ondragstart = drag;
    document.getElementById("#equal").ondragstart = drag;
    document.getElementById("#bigger").ondragstart = drag;
    document.getElementById("#smaller").setAttribute("ondragstart", "drag(event)");
    document.getElementById("#equal").setAttribute("ondragstart", "drag(event)");
    document.getElementById("#bigger").setAttribute("ondragstart", "drag(event)");
  });
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Import jquery and make the div with id 'draggable' draggable.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$( function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
 } );
</script>
```

The div that is draggable containing the image.

```
 <div id="draggable">
   <img id="image" src="blank.png">
 </div>
```

Now you can change the image inside the div that is draggable. and the div will always be draggable.

```
document.getElementById("image").src = "good.gif";
```

If you want to enable or disable the draggable div you can do so.

```
$('#dragBlock').draggable({disabled: true});
//or
$('#dragBlock').draggable({disabled: false});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set a callback for the `DragStart` event, you need to use:

```
document.getElementById("equal").ondragstart = drag;
```

There is a difference between an element property and an attribute.

When you use:

```
<img .. ondragstart="drag(event)" ..>
```

You're setting the element's `ondragstart` attribute but when you use:

```
document.getElementById("equal").ondragstart = drag;
```

You're setting the element's `ondragstart` property which should be set to a `function`.

If you want to set an element attribute's value from JavaScript, you can use the `.setAttribute(..)` function:

```
document.getElementById("equal").setAttribute("ondragstart", "drag(event)");
```

Comment: It doesn't function. When the child clicks the "NEW" button, the 3 squares on the top and the 3 squares in the middle should go back to their original state. I wrote the original state in the question above. Then I tried all combinations of what you told me to write (code also above). The pictures in the middle row come back OK, but they can't be moved. The one that was moved in the first round (one from the middle row) stays where it is instead of disappearing. "up3" shows a basket as a background image. Normally the basket should become visible again.

Comment: I also tried to use $("#container").html('etc. to reset all 6 divs. It doesn't function either. And it's not only that the pictures cannot be dropped, they don't move at all.